# How to fetch the whole last row for the end of each month

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to access the last row of each month using LINQ and lambda expressions however I'm not sure how to do it.

I've got as far as a grouping but the issue is I don't think it contains all the data in the row.

```
var tonerPrinterList = _tonerPrinterRepo.GetTonerPrinterForDevice(printerId, starDate, endDate, color).GroupBy(tp => new {tp.timestamp.Year, tp.timestamp.Month});
```

The data structure that is produced by GetTonerPrinterForDevice contains more columns than the timestamp for example nominalCoverage and printerID which I need all these columns

Comment: Group by month. Sort by date. Get the last one of each group.

Comment: @Christopher yeah that's what I'm looking to do just not sure how to go about doing it as I need all the data in the row

Comment: I have very limited skill in LINQ.I could do it in SQL or MySQL without issue however.

Comment: @Christopher well if you can demo in SQL feel free to post it, I might be able to transfer it in to LINQ

Comment: @CharlieHardy Please accept my answer if it fixed your problem. If not, you can add your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @Maxinoume sorry I just needed to run some unit tests on it first and then completely forgot that I'd had some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work.
You first order by dates, then you group by month, then you select the last of each group.

```
var tonerPrinterList = _tonerPrinterRepo.GetTonerPrinterForDevice(printerId, starDate, endDate, color)
    .OrderBy(tp => tp.timestamp)
    .GroupBy(tp => new {tp.timestamp.Year, tp.timestamp.Month})
    .Select(group => group.LastOrDefault());
```